# What is wrong with this code (EntityManager)?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jpa, entitymanager

It's not given any error in code, but when I run my server and access my form xhtml page is not shown my data from DB. I debug it and when is running till this piece of code, something happens here and no data it;s stored. Besides this, I checked data in DB after and all my records disappear. Please, help!

```
private EntityManager em;
    public FormCompanii(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AirportJPA");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        this.companii = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Companii c").getResultList();
        if (!this.companii.isEmpty())
            companie = this.companii.get(0);
```

Comment: could you please share code snippet related to persisting data to Db?

Comment: and your persistence.xml also that defines your DB. Crystal balls can only show so much